# Multiple Views Folder C# ASP MVC4

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, razor

I'm using the Razor Engine to render my views and i wanted to customize it a little bit to get a different behavior than the default one.

I have differents views for the same datas behind and i want to reuse them but i'm going to specify the change of sub-folder externaly.

So here's the tree :

- Views

  - 1

    - ControllerName

      - Files.cshtml
    - Shared

      - _Layout.cshtml
  - 2

    - ControllerName

      - Files.cshtml
    - Shared

      - _OtherLayout.cshtml
  - etc.

The only thing that differs is the subfolder, everything else is the same (except content of cshtml files ^^). How to switch to the right folder depending on my good will ?

My first approach (which isn't really succesful) was to create a CustomViewEngine (then call it in Global.asax) but now i got 404's. (id will be setted later with ViewBag to be dynamic)

```
public class CustomViewEngine : RazorViewEngine
  {
    public CustomViewEngine()
    {
      ViewLocationFormats = new[]
 {
 "~/Views/%1//{1}/{0}.cshtml",
 "~/Views/%1//Shared/{0}.cshtml"
 };
      MasterLocationFormats = new[]
 {
 "~/Views/%1/{1}/{0}.cshtml",
 "~/Views/%1/Shared/{0}.cshtml",
 };
      PartialViewLocationFormats = new[]
 {
"~/Views/%1/{1}/{0}.cshtml",
"~/Views/%1/Shared/{0}.cshtml"
 };
    }

    protected override IView CreatePartialView(ControllerContext controllerContext, string partialPath)
    {
      var id = "1";

      return base.CreatePartialView(controllerContext, partialPath.Replace("%1", id));
    }

    protected override IView CreateView(ControllerContext controllerContext, string viewPath, string masterPath)
    {
      var id = "1";

      return base.CreateView(controllerContext, viewPath.Replace("%1", id), masterPath.Replace("%1", id));
    }

    protected override bool FileExists(ControllerContext controllerContext, string virtualPath)
    {
      var id = "1";

      return base.FileExists(controllerContext, virtualPath.Replace("%1", id));
    }
  }
```

Comment: What's the actual question? Do you want to know how to make `id` dynamic?

Comment: That i think i can get it. The main problem is how to switch between views. If i change my id to "2" (dynamically or not) i want the engine to look for the views in the subfolder 2 etc.

Comment: Have you debugged your code? Does your code hit `FileExists` method? If not, then your `CustomViewEngine` is not used at all.

Comment: I'm 404'ing even before using anything... Even when i'm trying the basic thing of @alex-v-kostyukov by returning the correct path to my view (and de-activating that custom engine)

Comment: Then let us see what you have in your `Global.asax` file and in your route registration section.

Comment: `ViewEngines.Engines.Add(new CustomViewEngine());
      AreaRegistration.RegisterAllAreas();
      FilterConfig.RegisterGlobalFilters(GlobalFilters.Filters);
      AttributeRoutingConfig.RegisterRoutes(RouteTable.Routes);
      BundleConfig.RegisterBundles(BundleTable.Bundles);`

Global.asax

and for my routes i'm rerouting automatically everything to my default route which is /{culture}/{product}

Comment: How about first calling `ViewEngines.Engines.Clear()`? Test it.

Comment: Well don't know about where it came from the beginning i took an old version of my solution and made the changes with this article (that i used in the first place too) http://weblogs.asp.net/imranbaloch/archive/2011/06/27/view-engine-with-dynamic-view-location.aspx and now it works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are three ways to do this:

1. There is a way to do this with a good code sample, [look here](http://weblogs.asp.net/imranbaloch/archive/2011/06/27/view-engine-with-dynamic-view-location.aspx). All your params passed through `VirtualPathProviderViewEngine.cs`
2. You can easily use your views path in controller action: `return View("~/stack/en/owerflow.cshtml")`
3. You can get your params and combine with previous technic do this: `return View(RouteData.Values["id"]+"/stackowerflow.cshtml")`

Comment: The code I paste is mainly from code example in solution 1 so not working.
The second one is a basic one but working, i'm trying to check for another way than this one (but will go for it if needed to)

Comment: Something wrong in your solution because the first way, is that Microsoft recommend. It doesn't working in all samples or just your project? Did you try it on downloaded solution example?

Comment: Well, great answer i tried again 1 and 2 using an older version of my solution and it worked. I don't know from where the 404's came from